# Is video displayed over https?

Tags: flash, security, video, web, https

I'm looking at a number of video websites (Youtube, Dailymotion, etc) and trying to check if they're displaying their videos over https. Most of them allow viewing the video's page with https, but Firefox and Chrome often display "Mixed Content" warnings . What should I be looking at to try and determine if the videos are actually transmitted securely?

Comment: Try [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) from the Electronic Frontier Foundation for Firefox. That will ensure most content is delivered over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the network tab in Chrome (I believe Firefox has a similar concept). It allows you to see all requests made from your page, which would include videos / media content being loaded by the page.

Comment: I ended up using FlashFirebug for Firebug to get to the Flash content. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's Developer tool won't be able to display full HTTP response for flash. But FireBug on Firefox would clearly display all the communication happening in that tab.

Comment: I ended up using FlashFirebug for Firebug to get to the Flash content. Thanks!